# Normalized uv for shaderModifiers .fragment attached to SCNGeometry (SCNPlane)

Tags: scenekit, metal, fragment-shader, metalkit

seems quite difficult for me to get this info so I will ask here directly.

**Q:** How do I get the correct normalized UV when dealing with shaderModifiers .fragment attached to a geometry in a SCNNode?

**More info:**
SCNGeometry is SCNPlane and I want to make it half black, half white.

*The below all return wrong positions*

```
float2 uv = _surface.diffuseTexcoord
if ( uv.x > 0 ) { color = white;} else { color = black;}
```

```
float2 uv = _surface.diffuseTexcoord
if ( uv.x > 0.5 ) { color = white;} else { color = black;}
```

```
float2 uv = -1.0+2.0*_surface.diffuseTexcoord;
if ( uv.x > 0 ) { color = white;} else { color = black;}
```

```
float2 uv = _surface.diffuseTexcoord;
if ( uv.x > scn_node.boundingBox[0].x  && uv.x < (scn_node.boundingBox[1].x / 2 ) ) { color = white;} else { color = black;}
```

```
float2 uv = -1.0+2.0*_surface.diffuseTexcoord;
if ( uv.x > scn_node.boundingBox[0].x  && uv.x < (scn_node.boundingBox[1].x / 2 ) ) { color = white;} else { color = black;}
```

**EDIT:**

"How you are using the color variable?"
_output.color = color;

**UPDATE:**

Removing

```
myMaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(value1, value2 , 1)
```

did the trick.

**Applying 1/value1 and 1/value2 to uv will bring me back to the normalized value?**

**Also what is the normalized value for us in shaderModifiers? -1/+1 or 0/+1 ?**

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the `color` variable?

Here's a working example:

```
_output.color.rgb = step(_surface.diffuseTexcoord.x, 0.5);
```

Comment: That's a no go. I got the same behaviour. One fifth white, remaining black. There is a miscalculation on the uv . . .

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer to this question.
Hope will save time for the readers.

**Q:** How do I get the correct normalized UV when dealing with shaderModifiers .fragment attached to a geometry in a SCNNode?

**A:**

```
Usually x range is 0 <-> 1
```

```
Usually y range is 0 <-> 1
```

When you use SCNMatrix4MakeScale(Xvalue, Yvalue, Zvalue) on the node you have:

```
x range is 0 <-> Xvalue
```

```
y range is 0 <-> Yvalue
```